# How to convert string to decimal in Java

Tags: java

```
Integer str = 300;
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw");
file.seek(seek);
file.write(Integer.parseInt(String.format("%02x", Integer.reverseBytes(str)), 10));
file.close();
```

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2c010000"

How can save this value in the file?

Comment: I do not know why, but you're trying to save the string "2c01000" as a number. But that string isn't a number, so java cannot convert it.
I do nut have much experience with RandomAccessFiles, but why don't you use a BufferedWriter with a simple FileWriter?

Comment: Why are you converting an int to a string then back to an int?

Comment: Because I need to handle a binary file at the address 0xCC

Comment: @immibis I'm not sure what I'm doing, I just know where I'm going to lol (2c01)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip formatting and parsing, and go straight for this implementation:

```
file.write(Integer.reverseBytes(str));
```

The problem is that you are printing the number as hex, but you parse it back as a decimal. To parse the number back as hex, pass 16 for the last parameter of `parseInt`:

```
file.write(Integer.parseInt(String.format("%02x", Integer.reverseBytes(str)), 16));
//                                                                            ^^
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/nUzVfg)

Note: This is probably not what you want anyway: if you with to write all four bytes, not the MSB, do this:

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer
    .allocate(4)
    .putInt(Integer.reverseBytes(str))
    .array();
file.write(bytes);
```

Comment: Nice! but how to spend it for the RandomAccessFile write 2c010000? =/

Comment: OMG!
I do not know how, do not know for serving, but I know that the result was expected \ ô
Thks, I was almost giving up LOL

Answer (score 3):

When you give `String.format("%02x",...)`, you are telling the compiler to give you a Hexadecimal number.

But then you are trying to parse it as a decimal number. Hence the issue.

You should do either of these,

```
file.write(Integer.parseInt(String.format("%02d", Integer.reverseBytes(str)), 10));
```

or,

```
file.write(Integer.parseInt(String.format("%02x", Integer.reverseBytes(str)), 16));
```

Comment: Both options resulted in an unexpected output in the file `00` needed the operation resulted in `2c01`